# How to create a specific table in Html?

Tags: html, html-table

How can I build this table? I know that I can create class with property visibility:hidden and apply this class to the last 2 td tags. But maybe there is another method without using css.

[image]

```css
table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 50%;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="4">Table</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying style an element or changing its looks, so you can't avoid using css. `visibility: hidden` is probably your best option.

The reason why `colspan` and `rowspan` works is because they have something to compare to. The last four `td` elements all have `colspan="1"` so the `colspan="3"` element knows to make itself the width of three times of the `colspan="1"` elements. That is why you need to have four elements in the last row and hide two of them to achieve your affect.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a crude attempt using `<div>`s in `display:inline-block` mode. It does work, but you have to be very careful about the `width` and 
`height` attributes.

```css
div {display:inline-block; border:1px solid grey;height:60px;vertical-align:middle;margin-bottom:-1px;margin-right:-1px}
div.vert2 {width:59px; height:121px; float:left}
div.five {width:300px}
div.four {width:239px}
div.three {width:179px}
div.two {width:119px}
div.one {width:59px}
```

```html
<div class="five">Table</div><br>
<div class="vert2"></div><div class="three"></div><br>
<div class="two"></div><br>
<div class="one"></div><div class="one"></div>
```

Comment: key points in question: **table**(not divs) **no css if possible**(a. k. a simpler solution)

Comment: @awesomeguy - well, in that case this is just an illustration of how *not* to do it. ;-) In the end everybody is free to pick their own preferred solution.

Answer (score -1):

Use grid layout. It will let you build those kind of tables with no problem at all.

```css
.container {
      outline: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
      margin: 20px auto;
      display: grid;
      width: 400px;
      height: 240px;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
      grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
      grid-template-areas: 'bx1 bx1 bx1 bx1'
                           'bx2 bx3 bx3 bx3'
                           'bx2 bx4 bx4 null1'
                           'bx5 bx6 null2 null2';
    }
    
    .box {
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    
    .b1 {grid-area:bx1;}
    .b2 {grid-area:bx2;}
    .b3 {grid-area:bx3;}
    .b4 {grid-area:bx4;}
    .b5 {grid-area:bx5;}
    .b6 {grid-area:bx6;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="box b1"></div>
      <div class="box b2"></div>
      <div class="box b3"></div>
      <div class="box b4"></div>
      <div class="box b5"></div>
      <div class="box b6"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: key points in question: **table**(not divs) **no css if possible**(a. k. a simpler solution)